# Le « tin tie coffee bag » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, alimentation, mots-composés

Comment nomme-t-on ou décrit-on un « *[tin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tin#English) [tie](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tie#English) coffee [bag](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bag#English)* » ? On utilise souvent ce genre de sac que ce soit de papier ou en plastique pour le vente de café moulu ou en grains. On a parfois des emballages sous vide de café qui une fois ouverts disposent d'un « système » similaire pour la fermeture. L'« élément » du haut sert à éviter que ne se déroule le rebord qu'on a roulé. Il s'agit non seulement de traduire les termes mais encore de se demander si la préposition suffira pour agencer le *sac* avec le « mécanisme » servant à le fermer ou s'il faudra un verbe (participe passé), tout en évitant l'ésotérique. On notera que ce qui se trouve fixé au rebord supérieur du sac existe aussi sous différents formats comme objet à part entière et sert à des fonctions similaires avec d'autres types de sacs ; on aura un nom est une épithète, comme dans *tin tie*.

[image]
<sup><sup>Pour fins d'illustration.</sup></sup>

Comment: Comment dit-on au Québec ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je connais en France le système de fermeture de paquets alimentaires où l'on fait coulisser une baguette (ou tige) en plastique sur le bord supérieur qui a été soigneusement replié et aplati.

Il me semble que ce qui est décrit dans la question est un système où la baguette est beaucoup plus longue que la largeur du paquet de façon à pouvoir en replier les extrémités de chaque côté du paquet. Je n'ai jamais vu en France ce système (ce qui ne veut pas dire que ça n'existe pas, bien sûr), que la fermeture soit fixée ou non au paquet.

En cherchant sur des sites de vente en ligne j'ai trouvé des « barrettes de fermeture pour sacs en papier » vendus en anglais sous le nom de [tin ties](https://www.pouchdirect.fr/sachets-en-papier-kraft/tin-ties.html).

Un autre site propose ce même système de fermeture sous le nom  « [d'attache twist adhésive](https://www.packlinq.fr/attache-twist-adhesives-pour-sac-de-17-5cm-tta7wh.html) ». Dans la mesure où le système est assez souple pour être replié je trouve que le mot d'« attache » convient mieux que celui de « barrette », la barrette évoquant pour moi quelque chose de pus rigide. Il est précisé par ailleurs que ces liens adhésifs sont [en étain](https://www.packlinq.fr/attaches-twist-adhesives-pour-sacs-a-cafe-14cm-100-pieces-tt5sld.html).

Il existe aussi des [sacs à fermeture zip intégrée](https://www.pouchdirect.fr/sachets-stand-up/sachets-a-fond-plat-avec-zip/sac-standup-a-fond-plat-blanc-brillant-fermeture-zip-frontale.html) au sac mais je ne crois pas que ce genre de fermeture soit vraiment réutilisable après première ouverture.

Si je devais faire la traduction de *tin tie bag* pour un site de vente en ligne je proposerais certainement quelque chose comme : « sac refermable **avec** un système d'attache en étain repliable », ou « sac refermable **par** système d'attache en étain repliable ». Et en ajoutant peut-être « fixe » ou « adhésif » après « système » selon le cas. « Sachet » pouvant éventuellement être mis à la place de « sac », (ce serait *bag* dans tous les cas en anglais).

Nous avons donc encore un exemple de la concision de l'anglais qui peut exprimer en trois mots *tin tie bag* (analysables je suppose comme un substantif précédé de deux épithètes qui servent à décrire le système de fermeture) ce que le français exprime en cinq ou plus, une préposition (« avec » ou « par ») introduisant le mécanisme de fermeture.

---

Je me suis amusé à chercher comment d'autres sites en ligne anglophones pouvaient chercher à vendre ce type de produit à des francophones, je vous livre quelques résultats plutôt amusants (ou désolants ?).

Après un passage rapide sur les « [tin tie sacs](https://www.etsy.com/fr/listing/86424199/12-livre-kraft-tin-tie-sacs-cafe-lot-de?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=tin%20tie%20bags&ref=sr_gallery-1-15) », clair et transparent pour quiconque parle anglais, la « [boîte cravate](https://www.etsy.com/fr/listing/67799411/kraft-boite-cravate-cafe-et-cookie-sacs?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=tin%20tie%20bags&ref=sr_gallery-1-16) » ou le « [sac de cravate étain](https://www.etsy.com/fr/listing/70292549/sacs-de-cravate-etain-kraft-lot-de-10-w?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=tin%20tie%20bags&ref=sr_gallery-1-29) » m'ont quand même demandé quelques secondes de réflexion.

Comment: @suiiurisesse On replie soigneusement le rebord du sac et on fait coulisser la barrette sur ce bord replié.

Comment: Donc oui l'_attache_. Je pense à « flexible » pour la qualité de l'étain. Autrement je pense au p.p. « muni ». Pour le point sur l'anglais bien c'est relatif, oui c'est plus court mais si je construis un sac en scotchant des attaches, ça donne un _tin tie coffee bag_ aussi, et pourtant. Le français dans la forme choisie permet à toute personne de savoir très précisément de quoi il s'agit même sans l'avoir vu. Vive les prépositions !

Comment: L'exemple pris par l'OP est assez bon, même si j'ai déjà vu ce genre de fermeture pour d'autres contenus, il est vrai que les paquets de café l'ont très souvent

Answer (score 1):

> Sac à café (en papier, en plastique) [muni](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/munir) d'une attache flexible
>   (intégrée au rebord supérieur).

[Muni](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/muni) comme *doté de*.